Can one single USB cable be used for all appliances?
As I am decluttering my house, I find many USB cables of the same type. They came from many appliances that I have accumulated over the years.

Many cables with USB-A on one end, micro-USB on the other end
Many cables with USB-A on one end, mini-USB on the other end

One physical difference appears that some cables have ferrite cores (a cylinder), but some do not.
I also understand that charging cables and data cables differ in that the latter have more wires.
Can I use a high-quality cable for every appliance that fits it and throw away the original cables?

In general, a cable that supports a higher standard will be backwards compatible. Simply being newer isn't good enough. IF you're able to find a good cable that does meet the requirements of your most demanding devices, that cable should work fine for the lesser devices too.

Yes, any cable with the right mini/micro USB connector will work fine. Those USB sizes don't have a separate 3.0 standard like Type-A/B, so you don't have to worry about the versions
Cables with type-A/B USB connectors on both ends can be version 2.0 or 3.0, and the newer versions have more pins for increased power/data. They are backwards-compatible, so just having a newer USB cable is enough

While true, one should note that this does not apply for USB-C. I know its not in the question, but it doesn't hurt to mention this for others who find this question and think, well, I have USB-C, and USB is USB so its probably the same. But for USB-A to micro and mini, there are either power or power+data, and there could be USB A version 2 and 3, as the answer states, whereas USB-C has many different supported features inside the cable itself, including different bandwidths.

Surely this should be "Any cable that supports data" - there are some 2 wire cable abominations out there that only have +5v and ground with USB connectors on the end.
